# php check if abstract method exists

Tags: php, class, abstract

```
abstract class A{
   abstract test();
   function __construct (){
       //check if test method exists on B//
   }
}

class B extends A{

}

new B();
```

my question is ... is there a way to check if the `test` method exists on `class B`?
so I can avoid the fatal error ?

hope it makes sense.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The point of having the abstract method there is to remind you that classes extending `A` have to implement it (unless they aren't "instantiatable")

Comment: well the lets say i forget that it was abstract... then the error could be shown to the general public ... so I can put a different more user friendly error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
method_exists(get_called_class(),'test');
```

the above has solved my problem :) hope it helps someone out there.